# Question on the scope of using the keyword "Var"

Tags: c#, keyword

New to C# I have done a good bit of reading on learning the language and in the 2 full books and numerous site articles, do I ever recall reading about the keyword "var" usage not allowed within the class scope but needing to be within some nested element of the class (i.e. method).  I know you can declare the variable with an access modifier and type (i.e. string, int..etc.).

Even this site I can find question on using "var" but not regarding its limitation.

Maybe it is so obvious to every other individual that most writers does not make mention of this and I am the last reader on earth it isn't obvious to - would someone be so kind to explain the reason behind this?

NOT ALLOWED EXAMPLE

```
public class SomeClass
{
    var SomeVariable = new SomeClass();
}
```

ALLOWED EXAMPLE

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      var SomeVariable = new SomeClass();
   }
}
```

I can obviously declare

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public string SomeVariable;
}
```

Comment: See this blog post: [Why no var on fields?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're allowed to use `var` for local declarations, but not fields, basically.

[Eric Lippert's blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/) explains why. Essentially:

- It introduces some awkward situations where there's ambiguity
- It means working out a way of exposing anonymous types as part of a class's public interface, potentially
- It doesn't work well with the way the compiler is implemented (which may sound like the team is just lazy, but they need to prioritise work like anyone else)

(I certainly hope neither of your C# books was C# in Depth, 'cos I definitely mention it there... section 8.2.2 in both editions :)

Comment: Thanks for the details.  The two books I have referred to are; Pro C# 4 and .Net 4 and "Head First C#".   Just to be clear, they state in a couple places details about the use of the anonymous type var keyword and its use.  But I had not read why its use is limited not in the scope of the class itself.